# Изменить место появления SnackBar

Tags: android, android-studio

Есть рекламный баннер внизу экрана. И есть всплывающий SnackBar. При появление SnackBar перекрывает рекламный баннер. Можно изменить место появления SnackBar (чтоб всплывал над рекламным баннером)?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/cordinatorSaveList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvLists"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Вызов snackbar:

```
LinearLayout linList = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.linList);
Snackbar.make(linList, "Удалить список?", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show;
```

Comment: разделите основное view и баннер с рекламой разными layout'ами и привяжите snackbar к основному view

Comment: Пробовал, но SnackBar все равно вылазит внизу экрана, а не внизу LibearLayout-а к которому я его привязываю.

Comment: поверьте, то что я сказал - работает. Но т.к. Вы не выложили xml, я и другие не сможем помочь вам более точно. Прибегая к экстрасенсорике, я вижу один большой Layout, а в нем вы разделили view, как я и просил:) => не работает

Comment: Извините. Добавил код.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/cordinatorSaveList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/lvLists"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

**Результат:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. код, который я привел сюда, уже можно внедрять в ваш проект без страха и риска.

P.S.S `ListView` устарел, советую переписать под `RecycleView` (рано или поздно придется).

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо!:)

Comment: @Evgeny рад был помочь!:)

Comment: Теперь возникла обратная необходимость:) Нужно разместить SnackBar под рекламой и чтоб при появлении SnackBAr поднимался и рекламный баннер тоже. Не подскажите как реализовать?